# Angular $q multiple promises

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I am trying to do this:

1. Run fun1
2. Then after fun1 returns (promise resolves), run fun2 and fun3 in parallel (async)
3. Then after fun2, 3 return (promises resolve), run some fun4 with different input all in parallel
4. Then eventually run fun5 after all fun4 are resolved.

   ```
       $q.all({
           fun1: fun1()
       }).then(function(){

           return $q.all({
               fun2: fun2(),
               fun3: fun3(),
           });

       }).then(function(){

           var promises = [];

           for(var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1){
               promises.push(fun4(i));
           }

           return $q.all(promises);

       }).then(function(){
           fun5();
       });
   ```

fun 1~5 are all api calls similar to this pattern:

```
var funX = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/someURL'
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return;

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            return new Error();
        });
    };
```

I want to make sure they are running in the order I describe above. Looks like fun4 did not wait for fun2 and fun3 to return, and fun5 did not wait for all fun4 to return too.

Comment: Looks ok at a cursory glance. Any reason you're using `$q.all` for `fun1`?

Comment: probably all is not needed if it's just one promise, but all should work even if there's only one i suppose?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (using `$timeout`) ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/8cFEkMbrc08S1K6vLupi?p=preview. Everything appears to execute in the desired order

Comment: Also, the `success` and `error` methods are deprecated ~ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice

Comment: The only reason I can think of that it does not wait for all to complete is because one of the $http calls fails, and $q.all resolves early in case of failure. I believe the solution is to threat the error in the .error handler and return a non error value to continue the chain.

Comment: I am on v1.4.7, I was monitoring the console, doesn't look like it was because of the errors that trigger the resolve. Might be because I am using the old `success` and `error`. Will be testing with `then`.

Comment: Is your app throwing https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$http/legacy? If so, you probably should have mentioned that

Comment: No it did not, it's not throwing any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this issue by using the new api and get rid of deprecated `error` and `success`.

Answer (score -1):

As I said earlier, what's probably happening is that some of your `Promise`s are failing. The best way to guard against the `$http` `Promise`s failing would be to deal with the error in the `.catch()` (don't use `.success()` and `.error()` as they're deprecated) and return a *truthy* value.

Following is a test case trying to simulate your process failing (open up the console and see what gets logged):

```js
angular.module('Test', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($q, Factory) {
    $q.all({
        fun1: Factory.succeedFunc('1')
      })
      .then(function() {
        return $q.all({
          fun2: Factory.failingFunc('2'),
          fun3: Factory.succeedFunc('3')
        });
      })
      .then(function() {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          promises.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? Factory.failingFunc('4: ' + i) : Factory.succeedFunc('4: ' + i));
        }
        return $q.all(promises);
      })
      .then(function() {
        Factory.succeedFunc('5');
      });
  })
  .factory('Factory', function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
      failingFunc: function(msg) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('executing', msg);
        $timeout(function() {
          console.log('failed', msg);
          deferred.reject();
        }, 500);
        return deferred.promise;
      },
      succeedFunc: function(msg) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('executing', msg);
        $timeout(function() {
          console.log('succeeded', msg);
          deferred.resolve();
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
</div>
```

And here is what happens when you deal with the rejection and return a value in the `Promise`s' `.catch()` (though be careful not to throw in the `.catch()` as that will reject the newly created `Promise` too:

```js
angular.module('Test', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($q, IgnoreErrors) {
    var Factory = IgnoreErrors;
    $q.all({
        fun1: Factory.succeedFunc('1')
      })
      .then(function() {
        return $q.all({
          fun2: Factory.failingFunc('2'),
          fun3: Factory.succeedFunc('3')
        });
      })
      .then(function() {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          promises.push(Math.random() > 0.5 ? Factory.failingFunc('4: ' + i) : Factory.succeedFunc('4: ' + i));
        }
        return $q.all(promises);
      })
      .then(function() {
        Factory.succeedFunc('5');
      });
  })
  .factory('Factory', function($q, $timeout) {
    return {
      failingFunc: function(msg) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('executing', msg);
        $timeout(function() {
          console.log('failed', msg);
          deferred.reject();
        }, 500);
        return deferred.promise;
      },
      succeedFunc: function(msg) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log('executing', msg);
        $timeout(function() {
          console.log('succeeded', msg);
          deferred.resolve();
        }, 1000);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  })
  .factory('IgnoreErrors', function(Factory) {
    return {
      failingFunc: function(msg) {
        return Factory.failingFunc(msg).catch(function() {
          return true;
        });
      },
      succeedFunc: function(msg) {
        return Factory.succeedFunc(msg).catch(function() {
          return true;
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
</div>
```

Comment: *"return a truthy value"* ~ this is completely incorrect

Comment: Thanks, Phil, fixed it now. I was thinking about throwing an error in the `.catch()`.